# compose chained functions using the same parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I am trying to better understand functional composition in ramda.js and currently have a method in a class that looks like this:

```
const replace = (newItem) => function3(function1(newItem).function2(newItem));
```

I know in ramda.js for a simpler function like

```
const replace = (newItem) => function2(function1(newItem));
```

you could write it like

```
const replace = compose(function2, function1);
```

Is there a similar way to do the same with the initial function using functional composition / application or other ramda.js helper methods?

Comment: Duplicating the `newItem` argument is really much harder in point-free style. Don't try it.

Comment: @Bergi is right, if anyone wants to try this, don't. `R.compose(function3, R.converge(R.call, [R.compose(R.flip(R.invoker(1,'function2')), function1), R.identity]))` is not acceptable from a maintenance standpoint. It also increases the number of function calls an absurd amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your question is how to write

```
function1(input).function2(input)
```

In a functional way. If I am correct, here is how:

First let's create a function `method` that would give us a method of an object bound to that object:

```
const method = R.curry((name, object) => R.bind(object[name], object))
```

Using this function, we can rewrite our expression as

```
method('function2', function1(input))(input)
```

But we want something cleaner and more re-usable, right? So let's do some refactoring

```
method('function2', function1(input))(input)

method('function2')(function1(input))(input)

R.pipe(function1, method('function2'))(input)(input) // or use R.compose

R.converge(R.call, [
  R.pipe(function1, method('function2')),
  R.identity
])(input)
```

Now we can define our function `combine` like so

```
const combine = (fn, name) =>
  R.converge(R.call, [
    R.pipe(fn, method(name)),
    R.identity
  ])
```

And the expression becomes

```
combine(function1, 'function2')(input)
```

I hope my explanation is clear and it solves your problem :)

Comment: This works, method could be replaced with ramda's invoker function which does essentially the same thing. e.g. `R.converge(R.call, [R.compose(R.flip(R.invoker(1,'function2')), function1), R.identity])` so the solution to my issue is `R.compose(function3, R.converge(R.call, [R.compose(R.flip(R.invoker(1,'function2')), function1), R.identity]))` ~ Thanks! As a side note, it probably isn't worth using as it is fairly difficult to read / comprehend so I'll probably just use the non point free version.

Answer (score 2):

Ramda has two functions that should help with this.  The more standard one is [`lift`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lift).  Many functional languages have this concept.  One way to think about it is that it lifts a function which operates on values to create one that operates on *containers* of those values:

```
add(3, 5) //=> 8
lift(add)([3], [5]) //=> [8]
```

Functions can be seen as containers of values too.  Functions which return values of a given type can be considered containers for that type.

So we can lift your `function3` to operate not on values, but on containers for those values, and then supply it the input to those functions.  Here's an example with arrays as containers:

```js
const function1 = newItem => `function1(${newItem})`
const function2 = newItem => `function2(${newItem})`
const function3 = (v1, v2) => `function3(${v1}, ${v2})`

const combine = R.lift(function3)(function1, function2)

console.log(combine('foo')) //=> "function3(function1(foo), function2(foo))"
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

---

The less standard function is [`converge`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge).  This is focused only on functions, and not on arbitrary containers.  It works similarly in this case.  The function is created in one pass rather than the two for `lift`.  And that means the initial functions need to be wrapped in an array:

```js
const function1 = newItem => `function1(${newItem})`
const function2 = newItem => `function2(${newItem})`
const function3 = (v1, v2) => `function3(${v1}, ${v2})`

const combine = R.converge(function3, [function1, function2])

console.log(combine('bar')) //=> "function3(function1(bar), function2(bar))"
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

`converge` is only for functions, but it can work with polyadic functions.  `lift` will work only with unary ones.  `converge` is a Ramda-specific function.  I haven't seen it elsewhere.  So, if `lift` will work for you, I would suggest you choose it instead.

Comment: Thanks - This looks close, but the function I'm looking for chains off the result of the first. Your solution is `function3(function1(bar), function2(bar))` but I'm looking for `function3(function1(bar).function2(bar))` (note the dot) I was looking at converge before posting this question, but am not quite sure how to do it. I do believe it is possible using R.invoke and some variation of lift, converge, or compose, but I can't quite get it.

Comment: Ah yes, I did misread.  Ramda doesn't offer much to help with *methods*, focusing instead on *functions*.

Comment: Per the other answer provided, it is in fact possible, however the complexity to comprehend it makes the non point-free style much more reasonable so I'll probably stick to it